# How to get data from server without clicking on "submit" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

I have this message:

```
<h3 id="welcomeUsername">Hello, </h3>
```

And I want to fire up the following script:

```
function pageLoaded(){

        $.get( "/getUsername", function( data ) {
            $( "#welcomeUsername" ).append( data );
            alert( "Load was performed with data: "+data );
        });

    }
```

It basically adds the user's name to the welcome message. But this won't fire off automatically. How do I do it and make sure the client doesn't re-direct to a new page!

The server side code:

```
app.get('/getUsername', function(req, res){

sess=req.session;
if(sess.username!=undefined)
{
    res.send(sess.username);
}
else
{
    res.redirect('/loginPage'); //res.sendFile(__dirname +'/public/index.html');
}

});
```

Comment: To call method on document ready, you can use: `$(pageLoaded);`. `How do I do it and make sure the client doesn't re-direct to a new page!` If user not logged, it looks like your server side script redirect user to login page. Is it part of your question or what? Quite unclear what you are asking

Comment: A. Wollf: Sorry that is not the part of the question. Basically what I'm asking is, why doesn't the $.get() function work by itself? It is supposed to fetch the username but it's not communicating with the sever side. (I put a console.log() message to check if the server side was called. It wasn't. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code, is that a function is defined, but never called. In JQuery, you can call `$` with a function as an argument. If you do this, it will be loaded as soon as the HTML DOM tree is loaded. What you can do is add 
`$(pageLoaded)` at the bottom of your script, so you'd get this:

```
function pageLoaded(){

    $.get( "/getUsername", function( data ) {
        $( "#welcomeUsername" ).append( data );
        alert( "Load was performed with data: "+data );
    });

}
$(pageLoaded);
```

Comment: I added onload="pageLoaded()" in the body. The function gets called fine. It's the $.get() that won't work

Comment: 'wont work' can be anything. Do you have any more information on what doesn't work?

Comment: It never reaches the server side. I added a console.log() message to see if anything gets printed on the other side. It doesn't.

Comment: Then your url might be incorrect. The javascript you provided works for me.

Comment: the username is getting appended behind the message??

Answer (score 0):

You should call this function when the page is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function {pageLoaded();});
```

If you add this to your js, when the page is ready, the function will be executed.

Comment: No, actually the function is working fine. It's the $.get() function that won't run.

Comment: `$(document).ready(pageLoaded)` (or just `$(pageLoaded)`) - no need for the anonymous function when all it does is call `pageLoaded()`.